# Java translating error. I am trying to take user input and translate it to values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am making a translator that takes english and translates it into a made up language called *Talhamr*. To do this I take user input and make it into an array. Then I test it against a word bank array that contains english words with the corresponding Talhamr word next to it. If the english word works I want to replace it with the corresponding Talhamr word. Can any one help me code this? bellow is the code I have so far.

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Translator {
    public static String userInput = "";

    public static String[] wordBank = {"a/an","Ai","about","circa" /*...*/};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * getting input
         */
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Write something to be translated into ancient language: ");
        /**
         * formatting input
         */
        userInput.toLowerCase();
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] wordArray = userInput.split(" ");
        /**
         * Creating a, and preforming english to talhammir, translation
         */
        EtoT e2t = new EtoT();
        e2t.translateToTalhamr(wordArray, wordBank);
        System.out.println(wordArray[0]);
        /**
         * This is how I formatted the word bank. After I went to quizlet and changed all the spaces between rows and columns to "-"
         * String makeNice = ...;
         * System.out.println("\""+ makeNice.replace("-", "\",\""));
         */

    }//end of main method   
}//end of Translator class
```

Second class containing translation method:

```
public class EtoT {
    /**
     * establishing word bank to loop through and translate
     */
    public String[] wordBank = {"a/an","Ai","about","circa" /*...*/};

    public EtoT() {
    }

    public String translateToTalhamr(String[] wordArray, String[] wordBank) {
        for (int i=0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("'");
            for (int j = 0; j < wordBank.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(".");
                if (wordBank[j] == wordArray[i]) {
                    System.out.print(",");
                    wordArray[i] = wordBank[j + 1];
                } else {
                    wordArray[i] = wordArray[i] + "!";
                }
            }//end of inner word bank
        }//end of outer for loop
        System.out.println("\n" + wordArray.toString());
        return wordArray.toString();
    }//end of translateToTalhamr

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }//end of main method
}//end of EtoT
```

Comment: What is your actual problem / question?

Comment: Please read [ask] and make a [mcve].

Comment: Please mind that I truncated your word database to two example entry, since the whole database only bloated the question. If someone is interested in *Talhamr*, then he can check the version history

Comment: The above mentioned duplicate explains why `if (wordBank[j] == wordArray[i])` won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are comparing Strings using `==`. Because Strings are objects, that checks that they are the same object instead of if they have the same text. To correctly test this, you can use `string1.equals(string2)`

Specifically for you, in your `translateToTalhamr` function, you should have `wordBank[j].equals(wordArray[i])` instead of `wordBank[j] == wordArray[i]`.